# Easy way to change the FontSize of the whole html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any standard approach to changing the font size of the whole HTML document?

I'm thinking of two buttons, one that increases font size and another that decreases font size. Both of these buttons calls a JavaScript function;

```
function increaseFontSize(){
//Increase the font size for the whole document
}

function decreaseFontSize(){
//Decrease the font size for the whole document
}
```

### Question

How do I do this? Is there a more simple way than the one that I stated above?

**Edit**

I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), which comes with it's own CSS for each HTML element. Bootstrap defines the default (body) font size as **14px**.

Comment: Maybe changing `font-size` css style attribute for `<html>` element or/and `<body>` assuming that any other element override this property?

Comment: There are alot of elements that override that property, yea

Comment: This depends on how font sizes are set on the page.

Comment: *a more simple way?* - simpler than which one?

Comment: @ahmad - an invalid edit - how do you know that jQuery is being used?

Comment: Bootstrap is being used in this case, and Jquery is available for use. @Danko

Comment: @LcSalazar Simpler than the suggested approach using JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

You need to target the `font-size` style of the `HTML` element. You'll have to make sure that an initial value exists so that you can easily modify it.

You can do so in the following manner:

```
document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].style[ "font-size" ] = "10px"
```

All that is left to do is implement the increments of the value:

```
function increaseFontSize(){
    var existing_size = document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].style[ "font-size" ];
    var int_value = parseInt( existing_size.replace( "px", "" );
    int_value += 10;
    document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].style[ "font-size" ] = int_value + "px";
}
```

I would recommend using a few helper functions to clean up this code:

```
function extract_current_size(){
  var existing_size = document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].style[ "font-size" ];
  return parseInt( existing_size.replace( "px", "" );
}

function increaseFontSize(){
  var existing_value = extract_current_size()
  existing_value += 10;
  document.getElementsByTagName( "html" )[0].style[ "font-size" ] = existing_value + "px";
}
```

Comment: Wont work if the body element doesn't have font-size property in style

Comment: @Aditya - very true. I've added that requirement into my answer. The value has to exist before modifying it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This solution looks very clean. I don't know if you saw my edit, but I'm using Bootstrap and it comes with a default body font size value of 14px. I will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: This function does not seem to apply the new font size. It extractes the current font size(14) and increments successfully. But there is no changes made to the font size.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be if you use `em` units on your CSS and you can use `Jquery` this solution can works.

You can set a global value on the body then change that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fontSize = parseInt($('body').css('font-size'),10);
    $('.inc').on('click',function(){
        fontSize+=0.5;
        $('body').css('font-size',fontSize+'px');
    })
    $('.dec').on('click',function(){
        fontSize-=0.5;
        $('body').css('font-size',fontSize+'px');
    })
})
```

```css
body {
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.tit {
    font-size:3em;
}
.sub {
    font-size:2em;
}
.cont {
    font-size:1em;
}
.button {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tit">Main Title</div>
<div class="sub">Subtitle</div>
<div class="cont">Contents</div>
<div class="button">
    <a class="inc" href="#">Increase</a>
    <a class="dec" href="#">Decrease</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer , Wont work if the body element doesn't have font-size property in style ?

Comment: @Aditya will work since there is one default value for font-size .... and you still get that from the jquery var

Comment: This looks very nice. However, I'm using bootstrap (check my edit) and bootstraps default body font size is 14px. Additionally, bootstrap defines each HTML element with some kind of default font size values, also in px. How will this affect this solution?

Comment: @Marcus in nothing check here http://www.bootply.com/P01ZSeZzsC ... the problem is some elements in bootstrap have fixed font-sizes you will need to override those styles and use em but you can try.

Comment: Altough I'm thankful for your efforts, this approach would make me have to override each element that I intend to increase/decrease the font size value of. As of now, @Lix answer looks more cleaner and I will try it out first.